# Enforce assignment operator instead of copy constructor on initialization?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

I'm putting together my own (silly) Scalars/List/Hash (perl-like..) thing in C++.

I've come across a point having to dereference a Scalar into a List, and it does not work when attempted in initialization.

`List` several default constructors, out of which 5 range from `List()` to `List(Scalar, Scalar, Scalar, Scalar)`.

```
List stuff(1, 2, 3);
Scalar aref = stuff; // List overloads the (Scalar) cast operator

// the following line is the unwanted thing..
List failist = aref; // uses List::List(Scalar), so same as `List failist(aref);`

// however, these work
List thisworks;
thisworks = aref;
thisworks.operator=(aref);
```

List header:

```
class List : public Thing {
    std::vector<Scalar> stuff;
public:
    List();
    List(Scalar s1); // this gets called because initialization
    List(Scalar s1, Scalar s2);
    List(Scalar s1, Scalar s2, Scalar s3);
    List(Scalar s1, Scalar s2, Scalar s3, Scalar s4);
    List &operator=(const Scalar &other); // but i want this

    /* some getters/setters cut away */

    operator Scalar();
};
```

I'd really like to use `List mylist = listreference;`, how do I ?

Comment: I didn't get the question. Could you rephrase it using more words, possibly using code too?

Comment: @Nawaz Now better? The thing is that the compiler chooses to use the constructor somehow, I don't even know why. It just isn't logical. The constructor puts the reference into a new list, which is not what i want. It should instead copy the list using the assignment operator.

Comment: extremely many antipatterns here, including the `Thing` class, constructors that have unreasonable effects, getters and setters, implicit conversion from a list to a scalar, ... gosh! here's a suggestion: *use a `std::vector` directly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering if you don't want `List myList = scalar` to invoke the constructor, then why do you have it in the first place?

Anyway, make it explicit as :

```
explicit List(Scalar s1);.
```

That way, you would make the compiler to spit out error on line:

```
List myList = scalar; //error
```

and then you will have chance to correct yourself, either by writing:

```
List myList(scalar); //ok
```

Or,

```
List myList; 
myList = scalar; //ok
```

Note that you cannot make `List myList = scalar` to invoke `List& operator=(Scalar const&)`, you can however implement one in terms of other, or both in terms of some common `init` function to avoid code duplication. The latter approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. `List mylist = listreference;` means: create mylist object of type List with copy constructor. So you have 2 options:

1. Implement copy constructor via opeartor=
2. Do it with two lines of code: `List mylist = listreference;
   mylist = listreference;`